# How to override self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem Action?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to override `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`'s *target* and *action*,

I tried:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                                  target:self
                                                                  action:@selector(backButtonOverrideAction:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

it is working but i want to use the default arrow:

[image]

i also tried:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;
[backButton setTarget:self];
[backButton setAction:@selector(backButtonOverrideAction:)];
```

but unfortunately it's not working.. do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: What different action do you want? The back button has a specific action that users expect, so changing it is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, i know but i'll be like a back button of a browser.. 
Even `BarButtonSystemItem` dont have the icon for back button.. tsk.. Apple..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**STILL**, No direct access for changing ***target*** and ***action*** on `self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem`.

I ended up using the first one i tried... and get my (custom) image..

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(backButtonOverrideAction:)];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

while...

```
//this two lines of code are still useless, i just feel sorry for them.. 
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTarget:<#(id)#>];
[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setAction:<#(SEL)#>];
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Be aware that using the leftBarButtonItem as a back button causes the `UINavigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer` to stop working. If this is a concern see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942571/how-to-enable-back-left-swipe-gesture-in-uinavigationcontroller-after-setting-le/43433530).

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign action to back BarButton.
The solution for that is to create the custom back button.

Answer (score 2):

In swift 3.1

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    
// set navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem return to Root
let backToRootVCButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(backToRootVCAction))
self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(backToRootVCButton, animated: true)
```

}

```
func backToRootVCAction() {
    _ = self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Comment: the only problem is that this wont have the arrow

Answer (score 1):

This works for 11.3:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let BackItemIndex = 2
    if let subViews = navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews, 
        subViews.count > BackItemIndex {
            navigationController?.navigationBar.subviews[BackItemIndex].subviews.first?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doPerformAction(_:))))
    }
}

@objc func doPerformAction(_ sender: Any) {
    // some code
}
```

This solution is based on searching the active subviews until the corresponding to backBarButtonItem and then add a UITapGestureRecognizer, so that it captures the event on the element.

Comment: Please explain your lines of code so other users can understand its functionality. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the code but `doPerformAction` is not getting called on back button Tap. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

## "backAction" (new in iOS16)

> If a back button already appears in the navigation bar, setting this property replaces its action without modifying its appearance. Otherwise, setting this property generates a back button with the image or title from the action you specify, unless you use the UINavigationItemStyleEditor navigation style.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/3987966-backaction?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html) says:

> When specifying buttons for a navigation item, you must use
>   UIBarButtonItem objects. If you want to display custom views in the
>   navigation bar, you must wrap those views inside a UIBarButtonItem
>   object before adding them to the navigation item.

That means you simply cannot use the method-2 from your question. Whereas method-1 is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps you...

```
BOOL IsOK_Clicked;

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 IsOK_Clicked = NO;
}
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if(!IsOK_Clicked){
    //Do what you want in Back Click
  }
}
- (IBAction)btnCheckOut:(id)sender {
 IsOK_Clicked = YES;
}
```

**Or** You may add left bar button item to navigation bar and set your own selector function to it.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do something like

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.target = self;
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.action = @selector(backButtonAction:);
```

here you have to handle the pop for the controller also.